# How to handle gcm notification onReceive behaviour depends on notification type

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

I have 3 types of notifications in android received from GCM.Audio/Video call and msg. How to  open different activity on different notification. THis is how I open activity on click of notification.
GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);


}
```

Comment: I just noticed. This is pretty much have the same idea as to your question a few days ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handle different types of notifications in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065831/handle-different-types-of-notifications-in-android)

Comment: @McAwesomville In that I was trying to edit my code but was not able to do so ended with posting a new question..

Comment: Sorry. Can you elaborate? As how I understand it, you were trying to modify the code in your post?

Comment: @McAwesomville Yes..but evertime it was showing errors so have to post new question.. Do you have any solution

Comment: I can suggest an edit to your other post. Do you simply want this post to be added to the other one?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a flag which contains notification type on your response from server and take action accordingly. 
Here is an example on how to achieve that:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService 

String message = "";
String image = "";
String user_id = "";
String name = "";
String time_received = "";
String notification_type = "";

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    String jsonStr = data.getString("data");
    Log.i(TAG,"JSON: "+jsonStr);

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        message = json.getString("message");
        image = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("image");
        name = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
        time_received = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("created_at");
        user_id = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("user_id");
        notification_type = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("notification_type");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Image: " + image);
    Log.i(TAG, "From: " + name);
    Log.i(TAG, "User ID: " + user_id);
    Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    Log.i(TAG, "Time Receievd: " + time_received);

    sendNotification(message);

    switch(notification_type)
    {
        case "Audio":
        //Call your activity Here
        break;

        case "Video":
        //Call your activity Here
        break;

        case "Message":
        //Call your activity Here
        break;

    }


}


private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action)
            .setContentTitle("Someone Commented on your Song.")
            .setSubText("By "+name)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: here I am not sending any messages it is been handled by my application server.. I am only handling it.. Here where to place GCMBroadcastReceiver class.

Comment: How to get data from server if I am using onHandleIntent method of class IntentService.